# How to define a nonserializable property for TypeScript `class` or `interface`?

Tags: javascript, typescript

TypeScript

How to define a *nonserializable* (to JSON) property for TypeScript `class` or `interface`? I.e. I need something like this (JavaScript):

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'foo', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get: function(){return 'stuff';}
});
```

Comment: nonserializable to JSON

Comment: @Rajesh it will be `enumerable: true,
        configurable: true`

Comment: This can be fixed with decorator

Comment: Nope, `private` doesn't influence the emitted javascript

Comment: @AlekseyL.Thank you, I will use it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick example with decorators:

```
function configureProperty(enumerable: boolean, configurable: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        descriptor.enumerable = enumerable;
        descriptor.configurable = configurable;
    };
}

class Foo {

    name = 'test';

    @configureProperty(false, false)
    get bar() { return 'stuff'; }
}
```

** You need to enable `experimentalDecorators`